# Using boost/std libraries to parse date with timezone

Tags: c++, datetime, boost, std

I want to convert a input date string (no time provided in input) such as '2017-05-04' into a unix timestamp with the time being "00:00:01" and timezone being Pacific time ('America/Los_Angeles).

I'm not quite sure how to do this - I explored using `boost::posix_time::time_from_string` but it doesn't seem to handle timezones.
Any suggestions would be highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using boost, parse a posix::date_time (or a gregorian::date) and add the time-of-day and timezone while constructing your `local_date_time` object.

- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/date_time/gregorian.html
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/date_time/date_time_io.html#date_time.date_input_facet
- http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/doc/html/date_time/local_time.html#local_date_time_constr

Here's a demo - not even using the input facet, because in all honesty parsing it manually seems simpler here:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dba726f13d8696e)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>
#include <iostream>

struct MyTime {
    static boost::local_time::time_zone_ptr time_zone() {
        using namespace boost::local_time;

        static auto zone = [] { // one-time initialization
            tz_database db;
            //libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv is included with boost
            std::istringstream fake_db(R"("America/Los_Angeles","PST","Pacific Standard Time","PDT","Pacific Daylight Time","-08:00:00","+01:00:00","2;0;3","+02:00:00","1;0;11","+02:00:00")");
            db.load_from_stream(fake_db);
            return db.time_zone_from_region("America/Los_Angeles");
        }();

        return zone;
    }

    boost::local_time::local_date_time _value { boost::date_time::not_a_date_time, time_zone() };

    friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& is, MyTime& parsed) {
        unsigned short y, m, d;
        char delim;
        if (is 
                >> std::noskipws // optionally of course
                && is >> y && (is >> delim && delim == '-')
                && is >> m && (is >> delim && delim == '-')
                && is >> d)
        {
            using namespace boost::local_time;
            local_date_time ldt({y, m, d}, {0,0,1}, time_zone(), true);
            parsed._value = ldt;
            return is;
        }

        is.setstate(is.rdstate() | std::ios::failbit);
        return is;
    }

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, MyTime const& v) {
        return os << v._value;
    }
};

int main()
{
    {
        MyTime dt;

        std::cout << "Not parsed yet: " << dt << "\n";

        dt = boost::lexical_cast<MyTime>("2017-05-04");
        std::cout << "Parsed: " << dt << " (base utc offset: " << dt._value.zone()->base_utc_offset() << ")\n";
    }

    // errors
    for (auto err : { "2017-15-04", "3", "", "17-1-77", "2017/05/04", "2017-05-04 x" }) try {
        MyTime dt;
        dt = boost::lexical_cast<MyTime>(err);
        std::cout << "Should not have parsed: " << dt << "\n";
    } catch(std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << "'" << err << "': " << e.what() << "\n";
    }
}
```

Which prints:

```
Not parsed yet: not-a-date-time
Parsed: 2017-May-04 00:00:01 PDT (base utc offset: -08:00:00)
'2017-15-04': Month number is out of range 1..12
'3': bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
'': bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
'17-1-77': Year is out of valid range: 1400..10000
'2017/05/04': bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
'2017-05-04 x': bad lexical cast: source type value could not be interpreted as target
```

To use a full time-zone database, change `timezone()` to do something like

```
static auto zone = [] { // one-time initialization
    tz_database db;
    db.load_from_file("/home/sehe/custom/boost_1_62_0/libs/date_time/data/date_time_zonespec.csv");
    return db.time_zone_from_region("America/Los_Angeles");
}();
```

> Point to the location where your boost library is installed, or where you deploy a copy of that database

Comment: Added a full-blown example with test cases http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4dba726f13d8696e

Answer (score 3):

Using [Howard Hinnant's free, open source, C++11/14/17 timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html), you can do this with the following syntax:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

date::sys_seconds
my_parse(const std::string& in)
{
    using namespace std;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    using namespace date;
    local_seconds ls;
    istringstream infile{in};
    infile >> parse("%F", ls);
    assert(!infile.fail());
    return make_zoned("America/Los_Angeles", ls + seconds{1}).get_sys_time();
}

int
main()
{
    std::cout << my_parse("2017-05-04").time_since_epoch().count() << '\n';
}
```

This program outputs:

```
1493881201
```

Using a site such as http://www.convert-unix-time.com/?t=1493881201 you can confirm that 1493881201 corresponds to Thursday 4th May 2017 07:00:01 AM UTC, which is Thursday 4th May 2017 00:00:01 AM PDT.

Comment: Thanks @Howard! Do you also have a solution that doesn't use custom libraries because I don't have the flexibility to use them in my code unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

I also prefer not use custom libraries but the Howard Hinnant's library is far better then boost/date_time that depends on ".csv" file supplied by user. The HH's library collect the information directly from local timezone repository that is frequently updated by the system not requiring you to maintain. The HH's is also a proposal for std++ that I don't know why was not implemented yet.